# How to backup docker with multiple services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a docker-compose file with multiple services and each service has its own volumes. ( for example WordPress with one MySQL service and web service)

I want to have an everyday backup on a remote backup server.
what is best practice and how should I do this?

1. Is there any way to have a real-time replica for my databases and contents (MySQL and wp-contents for example)?
2. Should I get an image for each container and send to remote using SCP or FTP?
3. Should make a tar file from volume folders and send to remote using SCP or FTP?

Or is there any other suggestion?

Comment: use rsync to copy files. you can also schedule the rsync operation in crontab.

Comment: You have exported all things you needed in volume, then how you backup data without docker in the past, also do it now...

Comment: I've never take a backup and now I want do it on a remote server.

Comment: thanks.
rsync is a good idea. but if for realtime backup it seems lsyncd is better.
@mihai

Comment: I haven't used it so I couldn't say. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a very good way to live sync.
[lsyncd](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiBo_Hxj-zkAhURyKQKHXL1Ds4QFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Faxkibe%2Flsyncd&usg=AOvVaw0E-1FU85bi4VUFQKT_9vAf) is a very good package that works with rsync but it is live.

I've sync all of my volumes on second server.